# How to implement cache manager using std::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, caching, c++11, memory-management

```
#include <mutex>
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

// 
// Requirements:
//  1: the bitmap could be used by multiple thread safely.(std::shared_ptr could?)
//  2: cache the bitmap and do not always increase memeory
//@NotThreadSfe
struct Bitmap {
    public:
        Bitmap(const std::string& filePath) { 
            filePath_ = filePath;
            printf("foo %x ctor %s\n", this, filePath_.c_str());
        }
        ~Bitmap() {
            printf("foo %x dtor %s\n", this, filePath_.c_str());
        }
        std::string filePath_;
};

//@ThreadSafe
struct BitmapCache {
    public:
        static std::shared_ptr<Bitmap> loadBitmap(const std::string& filePath) {
            mutex_.lock();

            //whether in the cache
            auto iter = cache_.find(filePath);
            if (iter != cache_.end()) {
                if ((*iter).second) {
                    return (*iter).second;
                } else {
                    std::shared_ptr<Bitmap> newPtr(new Bitmap(filePath));
                    (*iter).second = newPtr;
                    return newPtr;
                }
            }

            //try remove unused elements if possible
            if (cache_.size() >= kSlotThreshold) {
                std::unordered_map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<Bitmap>>::iterator delIter = cache_.end();
                for (auto iter = cache_.begin(); iter != cache_.end(); ++iter) {
                    auto& item = *iter;
                    if (item.second && item.second.use_count() == 1) {
                        delIter = iter;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (cache_.end() != delIter) {
                    (*delIter).second.reset();
                    cache_.erase(delIter);
                }
            }

            //create new and insert to the cache
            std::shared_ptr<Bitmap> newPtr(new Bitmap(filePath));
            cache_.insert({filePath, newPtr});
            mutex_.unlock();
            return newPtr;
        }
    private:
        static const int kSlotThreshold = 20;
        static std::mutex mutex_;
        static std::unordered_map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<Bitmap>> cache_;
};

/* static */
std::unordered_map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<Bitmap>> BitmapCache::cache_;

/* static */
std::mutex BitmapCache::mutex_;

int main()
{
    //test for remove useless element
    char buff[200] = {0};
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Bitmap>> bmpVec(20);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        sprintf_s(buff, 200, "c:\\haha%d.bmp", i);
        bmpVec[i] = BitmapCache::loadBitmap(buff);
    }
    bmpVec[3].reset();
    std::shared_ptr<Bitmap> newBmp = BitmapCache::loadBitmap("c:\\new.bmp");

    //test for multiple threading...(to be implemenetd)
    return 0;
}
```

I am pure new to C++ memory management. Could you please give me a hint: Am I in the right way, or should I employ different design strategy or different memory manager policy(such as weak_ptr etc)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This reminds me of Herb Sutter's ["Favorite C++ 10-Liner"](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/My-Favorite-Cpp-10-Liner) talk at GoingNative 2013, slightly adapted:

```
std::shared_ptr<Bitmap> get_bitmap(const std::string & path){
    static std::map<std::string, std::weak_ptr<Bitmap>> cache;
    static std::mutex m;

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> hold(m);
    auto sp = cache[path].lock();
    if(!sp) cache[path] = sp = std::make_shared<Bitmap>(path);
    return sp;
}
```

Comments:

1. Always use `std::lock_guard` rather than calling `lock()` and `unlock()` on the mutex. The latter is far more error prone and not exception safe. Note that in your code, the first two return statements never unlocked the mutex.
2. The idea here is to track allocated Bitmap objects with a `weak_ptr` inside the cache, so the cache *never* keeps a Bitmap alive by itself. This eliminates the need for manual clean up of objects that are no longer used - they are automatically deleted when the last `shared_ptr` referencing them is destructed.
3. If `path` is never seen before, or if corresponding `Bitmap` has been deleted, `cache[path].lock()` will return an empty `shared_ptr`; the following `if` statement then loads the `Bitmap` with `make_shared`, move-assigns the resulting `shared_ptr` into `sp`, and sets `cache[path]` to track that newly created Bitmap.
4. If the `Bitmap` corresponding to `path` is still alive, then `cache[path].lock()` will create a new `shared_ptr` referencing it, which is then returned.

Comment: Too bad this cache doesn't do much caching. If I need a bitmap every frame to draw a background, it will load and discard it every time. It's more of a "loader/deduplicator" than a "cache/manager".

Comment: @DanielKO: It is certainly a kind of cache, only not one that retains elements on its own behalf. It only caches objects for as long as anyone keeps a reference alive. This can be a bad thing, but it can also be a good thing. You can easily have this cache do something different, too, by keeping an extra reference around (either for as long as a bitmap is needed at all, or maybe inside an object with a 5-10 frame lifetime which decrements a counter every frame, or such -- which might possibly allow for better operation in tight memory conditions since stuff isn't kept around indefinitely).

Comment: as of c++17, prefer scoped_lock to lock_guard

Comment: This method never delete released entries from map. We also need a cleanup routine to iterate the map and check whether `weak_ptr`s are expired.